# JAXB unmarshalling fails to return an element having substitutionGroup

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling, substitution

While unmarshalling an xml document, JAXB fails to unmarshall a complex type having substitution group name. The doucment comes with substitute name and JAXB unmarshal  process fails to bind the data with actual element.
And eventually I get an empty object for which data is arriving in xml document. Is this a bug in JAXB or am I doing something wrong here?

Note: The below schema clearly defines substitute name for the problematic complex element type ENBFunction. And there are no errors while unmarshalling "xn:ManagedElementOptionallyContainedNrmClass" but the data is not filled up in Java class "ENBFunction".

```
    <element name="ENBFunction" substitutionGroup="xn:ManagedElementOptionallyContainedNrmClass">
    <complexType>
      <complexContent>
        <extension base="xn:NrmClass">
          <sequence>
            <element name="attributes" minOccurs="0">
              <complexType>
                <all>
                  <element name="userLabel" type="string"/>
                  <element name="enbId" type="en:EnbId" minOccurs="0"/>
                  <element name="x2BlackList" type="xn:dnList" minOccurs="0"/>
                  <element name="x2WhiteList" type="xn:dnList" minOccurs="0"/>
                  <element name="x2HOBlackList" type="xn:dnList" minOccurs="0"/>
                  <element name="x2IpAddressList" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
                  <element name="tceIDMappingInfoList" type="en:TceIDMappingInfoList" minOccurs="0"/>
                  <!-- linkList attribute is to be added when defined in the IS -->
                </all>
              </complexType>
            </element>
            <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <element ref="en:EUtranCellFDD"/>
              <element ref="en:EUtranCellTDD"/>
              <element ref="epc:EP_RP_EPS"/>
              <element ref="en:ENBFunctionOptionallyContainedNrmClass"/>
              <element ref="en:DeNBCapability"/>
              <element ref="xn:VsDataContainer"/>
            </choice>
            <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <element ref="sp:ESPolicies"/>
            </choice>
            <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <element ref="sp:SONControl"/>
            </choice>
            <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <element ref="sp:SONTargets"/>
            </choice>
          </sequence>
        </extension>
      </complexContent>
    </complexType>
  </element>
```

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: @lexicore, Thanks for your suggestion. Modified the content now.

Comment: The problem is resolved now, managed to find out the root cause. It seems while creating JAXBContext, instead of supplying specific jaxb class names as parameters to JAXBContext.newInstance method, I had to provide all the package names (colon separated) as a single string to JAXBContext.newInstance method. This solved the issue and unmarshalling is happening fine for the jaxb class for which the data is arriving in xml with its substitute name. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was in the way I was creating JAXBContext instance. JAXB provides more than one way for creating JAXBContext instance:

```
static JAXBContext  newInstance(Class... classesToBeBound) 
       Obtain a new instance of a JAXBContext class.
static JAXBContext  newInstance(Class[] classesToBeBound, Map<String,?> properties) 
       Obtain a new instance of a JAXBContext class.
***static JAXBContext   newInstance(String contextPath) 
       Obtain a new instance of a JAXBContext class.***
static JAXBContext  newInstance(String contextPath, ClassLoader classLoader) 
       Obtain a new instance of a JAXBContext class.
static JAXBContext  newInstance(String contextPath, ClassLoader classLoader, Map<String,?> properties) 
       Obtain a new instance of a JAXBContext class.
```

Initially I was using the first one,

```
static JAXBContext  newInstance(Class... classesToBeBound)
```

in which I was supplying all the jaxb classes to be bound, which somehow was not working. It worked when I used the third way of object creation which takes a single string having colon separated package names where all the jaxb classes are residing.

```
static JAXBContext   newInstance(String contextPath)
```